# Get data from two table in dynamo db

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am using dynamo db(no sql) in .net

I have two table is bellowing

1. Item (itemid , itemname)
2. Category (categoryid , categoryname, itemid)

so there i want to access { itemid ,itemname,categoryid,categoryname)

and how i create table structure .

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please provide more information -- for example, what have you tried so far, do you have some sample code, what is the relationship between the tables?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL (non-relational) database, which means **it is not possible to "join" tables together**.

If you wish to combine information from these two tables (eg via `itemid`), you would need to retrieve data separately from each table and combine the information **within your application**.

You can **create indexes on tables** (eg the Category table might have an index on `itemid`) that would make it easier to retrieve specific data.

Comment: Is this more inefficient? I have been starting to appreciate SQL more because of this limitation.

Comment: @FrederickHaug SQL is great because it is so flexible. However, it is not possible to predict how long an SQL query will take, especially if it uses JOINs. The benefit of a NoSQL database like DynamoDB is that is has **fully predictable performance**, which is important if it is powering large applications. It guarantees exactly how many Reads/Writes a table can provide each second, which SQL can't do.